# Magento 2 : Menu does not appear on home page

Tags: cache, varnish, magento2.2.4, magento2-enterprise

In Magento 2.2.4 **Community**Or**Enterprise** edition default menu not appear on  home page when enabled **Varnish Cache**.

Actually problem is related to **Varnish Cache** if I set **Varnish Cache** from `Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Full page cache -> Caching Application Set to **Varnish Cache**` then menu is not displaying.

If I set to **'Built-in cache'** then it's working fine.

[image]

But on other all pages it's appear.

[image]

I checked and found that **JS** is not showing in inspect element on home page, so reason for this menu is not displaying.

in inspect element on home page showing like this

```
<esi:include src="http://127.0.0.1/rb-ee/page_cache/block/esi/blocks/%5B%22catalog.topnav%22%5D/handles/WyJkZWZhdWx0IiwiY21zX2luZGV4X2luZGV4IiwiY21zX3BhZ2VfdmlldyJd/"></esi:include>
```

Can anybody know it is necessary to select **Varnish Cache** (Magento Enterprise Edition 2.2.4) and what happens if we not select  **Varnish Cache**?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Go to admin if cache enable then you can disable cache after check working ya not working ?

Comment: Thanks @PrashantPatel i was tried all basic configuration settings & run all related command.

Comment: The problem can be due to some JS error. Please check the browser's console for the errors and resolve accordingly to fix the issue.

Comment: Is that menu html rendering?  have you checked browser console logs.

Comment: Yes @MohitKumarArora it is related to JS problem, JS is not showing only on home page rather then other pages JS is showing & menu is working.

Comment: This need to be REOPEN because it is occurring in Default Magento Theme.

Comment: Be detailed: Please check my updated question, it is not about external extension or plugin, this is occurred in default "Magento  Community edition or Enterprise edition" every one can reproduce this issue in own environment. i would like to request to community member to please reopen this question. if you still think something is wrong then let me know i will explain. Thanks.

Comment: maybe this helps https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/100128/146

Answer (score 3):

This is an old M2 issue [Varnish top navigation menu gone](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112310/varnish-top-navigation-menu-gone)

Even then all roads lead to github where there are similar reports like https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3897 but the vanishing menu has been plaguing users forever in M2.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this problem, you can override the default.xml file and remove it inside the ttl tag of the topmenu block, this xml find in Vendor/Magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why `TTL tag` added in `default.xml` and what is the use of `TTL tag` and what happens if we remove `TTL tag`?

Comment: It serves to say if the block should be cached, then removing that tag from the topmenu block it will not be cached and will work again, I will see other better solutions, but this was the first one I found, to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Because of Varnish it happens in latest Magento2.4.1 as well..
Why don't you follow the below steps to get this done?

Overwrite default.xml located at /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/
search for ttl="3600" written inside " block and simple remove ttl="3600"
It should work now

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem in my magento 2.4.6 instance. my menu is not coming and the block section is loading with a cache URL like this.

```
<esi:include src="http://basetheme.hww/page_cache/block/esi/blocks/%5B%22custom.navigation%22%5D/handles/WyJkZWZhdWx0IiwiY21zX2luZGV4X2luZGV4IiwiY21zX3BhZ2VfdmlldyJd/"></esi:include>
```

**Problem:** The problem was the **ttl** attribute in the block call in XML.

**Solution:** I have just removed the **ttl="3600"** attribute from the XML block call, which was fixed for my case.

**Reference:** https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento-2-2-4-EE-Menu-is-not-appear-on-home-page/m-p/533869#M15741