# Topmenu Nav not Rendering

Tags: magento2, navigation

Does anyone have advice on how to debug why the main navigation wouldn't be rendering on my site? It's definitely caused by my custom module (which extends Nav's Topmenu.php), but everything's working locally so I'm having difficulties determining why.

Any tips would be appreciated!

**Edit: Are there any logs I could check / ways of determining where exactly in the process that this fails?**

Here's my code for Topmenu.php:

```
namespace Ibex\Nav\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{
    /**
     * Get top menu html
     *
     * @param string $outermostClass
     * @param string $childrenWrapClass
     * @param int $limit
     * @return string
     */
     protected function _getHtml(
         \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
         $childrenWrapClass,
         $limit,
         $colBrakes = []
     ) {
         $html = '';

         $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
         $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
         $childLevel = $parentLevel === null ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

         $counter = 1;
         $itemPosition = 1;
         $childrenCount = $children->count();

         $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
         $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

         /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $child */
         foreach ($children as $child) {
             if ($childLevel === 0 && $child->getData('is_parent_active') === false) {
                 continue;
             }
             $child->setLevel($childLevel);
             $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
             $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
             $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

             $outermostClassCode = '';
             $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

             if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
                 $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
                 $child->setClass($outermostClass);
             }

             if (count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake']) {
                 $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
             }

             $href = 'href="' . $child->getUrl() . '"';
             $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
             $html .= '<a ' . $href . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $this->escapeHtml(
                 $child->getName()
             ) . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                 $child,
                 $childLevel,
                 $childrenWrapClass,
                 $limit
             ) . '</li>';
             $itemPosition++;
             $counter++;
         }

         if (count($colBrakes) && $limit) {
             $html = '<li class="column"><ul>' . $html . '</ul></li>';
         }

         if($childLevel == 2){
           $html .= '<li><a href="#" class="shop-all">Shop All</a></li>';
         }
         return $html;
     }

     /**
      * Add sub menu HTML code for current menu item
      *
      * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $child
      * @param string $childLevel
      * @param string $childrenWrapClass
      * @param int $limit
      * @return string HTML code
      */
     protected function _addSubMenu($child, $childLevel, $childrenWrapClass, $limit)
    {
        $html = '';
        if (!$child->hasChildren()) {
            return $html;
        }

        $colStops = null;
        if ($childLevel == 0 && $limit) {
            $colStops = $this->_columnBrake($child->getChildren(), $limit);
        }

        $extraclass = 'isactive';

        if ($childLevel == 0) {
          $html .= '<div class="megamenu-wrapper"><div class="megamenu">';
          $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . ' ' . $childrenWrapClass . ' ' . $extraclass . '">';
          $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, $colStops);
          $html .= '<li class="level1"><a href="shop.html"><span>Shop All Categories</span></a></li>';
          $html .= '</ul>';
          $html .= $this->getChildHtml();
          $html .= '</div></div>';
        } else {
          $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . ' ' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
          $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, $colStops);
          $html .= '</ul>';
        }

        return $html;
    }

}
```

Aside from this, there's just CSS -- no layout/template files that could be interfering. Very odd. Any assistance in pinpointing the error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share the layout module content, we will try to debug this

Comment: Thanks! Edited into the above. Apologies if your eyes roll out of your sockets while looking into what I'm doing here. Again, it's working great locally, so I'm having a difficult time troubleshooting it.

Comment: So you tell me, your code works fine and not with your custom theme right ?

Comment: Right, works fine on a local copy of the custom theme, which is pretty basic / extended from Blank.

Comment: Can you share me the layout.xml `app/code/Vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/some_name_here.xml`

Comment: The module actually doesn't have any layout updates.

Comment: Really ? and how do you want it to be displayed, give the phtml path

Comment: ...Really. There was no need to change the position of any blocks, just added some markup to the main navigation. I'm gathering that that's, like, _foolish_ or something?

Comment: have you run required commands?

Comment: Of course, all commands have been run.

Comment: can you share di.xml file code and path? Is there any other module who overriding  same file?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Ibex\Nav\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>`

And I've tried disabling all other non-Magento modules and the problem persists

Comment: please confirm that module `Ibex_Nav` exist in `/app/etc/config.php` file.

Comment: Yeah, it's there and enabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82517/discussion-between-kunj-and-brockfast-cowboy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, I would've never thought that this would be the solution, but it turns out that removing the block and re-adding it without the TTL parameter was the fix:

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>

<referenceBlock name="store.menu">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav.fix" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

Thanks to Gabriel in this thread:
[Magento 2 https ssl missing navigation menu](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99768/magento-2-https-ssl-missing-navigation-menu/169970#169970)

Comment: The `TTL` is an issue if you have "Varnish" enabled in your config but don't have the Varnish in your local. Just switch from Varnish to Built-in (remove the `http_cache_host` in the env.php too). What is the point of enable Varnish in configuration but not using it?

Comment: Hi brackfost, i have issue in hamburger menu, any help thanks,  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328503/57334

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons, but based on the approved answer, seems it is based on **Full Page Cache** Configurations

`./vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml:69`

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
```

This has the **ttl=3600** which instructs the caching mechanism to refresh the menu cache entry every 1 hour.

[image: Store > Configuration > Advanced > System]
Varnish cache is recommended and shipped with Magento 2 out of the box. Make sure if you **have enabled Varnish cache** instead of Built-in Cache (File based) in your local environment **without configuring Varnish service properly**.

If yes then **main menu will disappear**. (Because Magento will replace the menu block with a Varnish compatible ESI block but varnish is not there to decode it!)

`<esi:include src="http://test.loc.com/rb-ee/page_cache/block/esi/blocks/%5B%22catalog.topnav%22%5D/handles/XXXXX/"></esi:include>`

Hope this helps.