# Top navigation menu merge with accout button

Tags: topmenu

New to Magento 2, so sorry if I'm asking silly question, but i really need some help here. My boss wanted to create a new website using the new Magento 2.3 for his company. So we bought hosting, install Magento 2, give permissions, install theme etc.

I'v created a top menu navigation according to my boss likes about witch category to appear in the top of the menu and to set up the way he likes it. The theme is responsive and he likes it, but there is a bug of the css or simply of the menu rendering showing on the picture below. The Add to cart button, The wish list button and the, Add to cart button.

I simply tried to rearrange the categories in the Catalog->Categories , and there is a bit of satisfaction in there, if i make it that way. But because of responsiveness of the theme on other devices the menu and the buttons still appears that way on the scree(see screenshot).

Pls help.

I tried this -> [Topmenu Nav not Rendering](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239777/topmenu-nav-not-rendering)

Working on this solution right now, but I'm not sure will it help.

Any advice is gratefully appreciate

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue cause you have many categories show on top menu. You can go to Admin Panel > Stores > Configuration > Magiccart > Magic Menu > Not Include Top Menu => Select and hidden some menu will look good.

Also you can read more docs below this link: https://themeforest.net/item/expert-premium-responsive-magento-2-and-1-support-rtl-magento-2-/21667789

If you need more help, you can open a ticket at https://alothemes.com/ticket/

Thank you!